# sql calling columns of the same name from two different tables

Tags: sql

i am trying to solve this

"Show the detail for cage number 144. Include the name of the animals in this cage, along with the keeper name that looks after the cage, and the keeper name that looks after each animal in the cage. Include the species name for each animal in cage. The data should show each animal from oldest to youngest"

here's my query:

```
SELECT a.cageno, c.name AS "animal name", a.keeperID, 
       b.surname AS "cage keeper", c.keeperID,b.surname AS "animal keeper", 
       d.name AS "species name"
FROM cage a, keeper b, animal c, specie d
WHERE a.cageNo = 144 AND c.keeperID = b.keeperID 
ORDER BY c.DOB DESC
```

the problem here is that i would like to get the animal keeper's name from the keeper table but it has been used for the cage keeper's name as well 
so basically i am trying to get a separate set of names for the cage keeper as well as the animal keeper
how do i solve this??

Comment: You should look into SQL `Join` statements. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: How are the tables related? Could you please describe their structure?

Comment: You'll need two joins to the keeper table one for the cage keeper and one for the animal keeper then by aliasing the tables differently, you can get the desired results.  Assuming cage and animal both have a "Keeper" ID.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you need one column to be selected twice. It should be possible to do it as in your example (not 100% sure, don't have here a SB server to try). If it does not work, you can use one table twice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this assuming cage has keeperID and it's the foreign key to keeper table.

```
SELECT a.cageno, c.name AS "animal name", a.keeperID, e.surname AS "cage keeper", 
       c.keeperID, b.surname AS "animal keeper",  d.name AS "species name"
FROM cage a, keeper b, animal c, specie d, keeper e
WHERE a.cageNo = 144 
  AND c.keeperID = b.keeperID
  AND a.KeeperID = e.KeeperID
ORDER BY c.DOB DESC
```